# Where to find topographic basemap with no labels

Tags: qgis, basemap, topography

I am new to QGIS and trying to find a simple topographical basemap for Britain and Ireland. It is a map of prehistoric sites, so I can't have any cities/streets/labels, just topography.

Comment: If its a basemap based on open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-raster-data/50m-natural-earth-2/

https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/10m-natural-earth-2/

> Natural Earth 2 – This data derived from Natural Earth 1 portrays the
> world environment in an idealized manner with little human influence.
> The softly blended colors of Natural Earth 2 are ideal for historical
> mapping, because it shows the world much as it looked before the
> modern era.